# Change the value of a global variable inside a for loop

Tags: java

I am creating a small program, for a school assignment, in which people can input their running history (miles run, time elapsed) and see their potential 10K pace and marathon pace times. After the paces are displayed, a table of different paces is displayed.

I have a global variable (pace) which most of the calculations run with that needs to be altered inside a for loop but will not update for the calculations.

edit: I understand this program is poorly written and there's a lot of stuff that could be condensed. However, it works and will satisfy the parameters of the assignment. Inside the for loop, the variable "pace" needs to be increased by 30 with every iteration of the loop.

```
public class MarathonTime {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name;
    double distance;
    int hours, minutes, seconds;
    double pace;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is your first name? ");
    name = scanner.next();
    System.out.print("How many miles did you run today? ");
    distance = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("How long did it take? Hours: ");
    hours = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Minutes: ");
    minutes = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Seconds: ");
    seconds = scanner.nextInt();

    pace = ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds) / distance;
    double marathonPace = pace * 26.2;
    double tenKPace = pace * 6.2;

    int paceMinutes, paceSeconds;
    paceMinutes = (int) pace / 60;
    paceSeconds = (int) pace % 60;

    int marathonHours, marathonMinutes, marathonSeconds;
    marathonHours = (int) marathonPace / 3600;
    marathonMinutes = (int) (marathonPace % 3600) / 60;
    marathonSeconds = (int) marathonPace % 60;

    int tenKMinutes, tenKSeconds;
    tenKMinutes = (int) tenKPace / 60;
    tenKSeconds = (int) tenKPace % 60;

    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    System.out.print("Your pace is "); timeFormatPace(paceMinutes, paceSeconds);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("At this rate your marathon time would be ");  timeFormatMarathon(marathonHours, marathonMinutes, marathonSeconds); 
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("and your 10K time would be "); timeFormat10K(tenKMinutes, tenKSeconds);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Good luck with your training!");
    System.out.println();

     for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            if(i == 1) {
                System.out.println("Pace \t\t 10K Time \t\t Marathon Time");
                i++;
            }
            if(i == 2) {
                System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
                i++;
            }
            // input the tablePaces into the calcs and print them as the format
            pace = (281 + (i*30));

            if (i >= 3 && i <= 10) {

            timeFormatPace(paceMinutes, paceSeconds); System.out.print("\t\t "); timeFormat10K(tenKMinutes, tenKSeconds); System.out.print("\t\t\t ");
            timeFormatMarathon(marathonHours, marathonMinutes, marathonSeconds);
            System.out.println();
            }
     }  
}
```

Comment: You can use a `temp` variable inside the loop for calculation purpose alone

Comment: `pace` is not a global variable by any reasonable definition. And I don't see a question.

Comment: `pace` is also a local variable here declared inside `main()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do (very condensed):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int pace = 100; // or initialise to whatever

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // do something

        pace = pace + 30; // or equivalently, pace += 30
    }
}
```

In future, try to reduce your problem to a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The process of doing this will often help you solve the problem yourself, but at the very least it makes it easy to for someone else.

Also, if you know your program is poorly written, fix it! Well written, concise, modular programs are much easier to reason about. Messy, complex code is difficult. You will thank yourself in less time spent debugging, and you'll get a better grade too.